# Passing parameter array with different data types via ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, parameter-passing, prepared-statement

I'm programming a small CRUD interface with js, PHP and MYSQL. To avoid SQL injection, my javascript is separately POSTing a prepared SQL statement `form._source` and an array containing the parameters `form._param`

```
  _post = {action:'read', source:form._source};
  if (form._param !== null) _post['param']=form._param;
  $.post("/ajax/crud.php",_post, function(result){
    if (!result.error) {
      form._record = result.data;
      form._totrec = result.data.length;
      form.gotoRecord(setrec);
    }
    else {}
  }, "json");
```

The parameter array can contain different datatypes, like for example:

```
form._source = "SELECT * FROM z_country WHERE continent_code = ? AND pop > ?"
form._param = ["E", 50];
```

In php, the `param` array is cast into string in the $_POST variable, the `var_dump($_POST);` gives me:

```
array(3) {
  ["action"]=> string(4) "read"
  ["source"]=> string(56) "SELECT * FROM z_country WHERE continent_code = ? LIMIT ?"
  ["param"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(1) "E"
            [1]=> string(2) "50"
  }
}
```

So, what's the best strategy to avoid losing the information that the second parameter is actually a number (an integer), not a string. I understand that ajax and php 'communicate' via strings, but I need mysql to do a numeric comparison to the parameter, not an alphanumeric one.

- I could of course have php analyze the content of $_POST, but that would possible lead to errors, if I wanted for example a phone number to be interpreted as a string.
- Is there a way to tell $_POST how to interpret its content, when the ajax call has a mixed array as one of the parameters?
- The other idea I had was to prepare the 'param-type' string ('si' in the above example) in javascript and send that along with the ajax request

All a little unsatisfactory for a standard situation. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: You are going to have to prepare that statement, and therefore will have to bind values to the paramters, thats one place where the type gets applied, although most of the typing will be done by the database as it knows what type a column is. I get the feeling you are trying to solve an issue you dont really have

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The parameter array is passed on from js via ajax via $_POST to php. In php, I'm preparing the statement and binding the parameters. The problem is that js has the correct types in the parameter array it is passing to php, but in php they all appear as a string.